# Convert projected coordinates to regular GPS ones in android

Tags: android, gps, geojson, map-projections

I have an app that parses a GEOJSON file, so far so good, but when I tried to calculate distances I saw strange results.

Then looking at the JSON file in detail, I realized that the coordinates were not expressed in regular GPS format as you can see in this excerpt of json. I googled that and found out that they are projected coordinates which I've never heard about.  So far I haven't found a way to transform them into regular GPS.

```
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 726477.996, 4371836.896 ] }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can also try out [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) and find [discussions like this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80367/how-to-convert-6-7-digit-coordinates-to-degrees-latitude-longitude) for example. So, those are some sort of "flat earth" coordinates probably expressed in meters from certain references like the equator and zero meridian for example. (But I don't know what are the references in this case.) Maybe the source of the `GeoJSON` data has defined the projection details somewhere(?)

Comment: Thanks, I did tried gis, but nothing, and unfortunately, the source is rather lazy, and there was not anything there but the json

Comment: Any luck finding solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to obtain transformation rule: if You know coordinated of several object in your JSON file and in WGS-84 (for example on Google Maps) You can calculate transformation coeffs and probably rule. For beginning just try to visualize objects from JSON and compare that image with image on Google maps. And take a look at `bbox` tags in your JSON file.

Probably, You has same GeoJSON as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18043564/6950238) and it is  most likely the coordinate system is some variation of State Plane or UTM as [lreeder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215651/lreeder) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18044140/6950238).

Comment: Thanks, that gave me a clue. I found out that the coordinate system is EPSG:25830 ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N. However, I am trying to find the algorithm to transform it into long, lat GPS.  Any clues?